# Django + jQuery + Ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I've a page with a text field at the top, a submit button and below, a list of messages.
I want that when you click on submit after you wrote something in the textfield, the application saves the new message in database and display it without refreshing page, with Ajax. The new message should appear at the top of message list. (I want a slide-down effect for the new message)

Now, I've wrote something like this:

```
$("#message_form").submit(function() {
    var dataString = $("#message_form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/send_message",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(html) {
            // what here?
        });
    });
});
```

I'm a newbie and I don't know what to write here and in the new function in `views.py`:

```
def send_message(request):
    // what here?
```

Please, can you give me help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this maybe?

```
def send_message(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    message = MessageForm(request.POST)
    message.save()

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'result' : 'success'}), mimetype='application/javascript')
```